# Application of l'Hospital rule

Tags: limits

I have a smooth function $f(x)$, with $f(0)=0$ and $f \in C^{\infty}([0,1])$, on $[0,1]$ and I'm trying to prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous on the complete interval and thus belongs to $L_2([0,1])$. I believe that I can apply l'Hospital rule to prove my assertion, however I'm not too confident, kindly critique my following reasoning:

Since $f(0)=0$, we obtain $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{0}{0}$, an intermediate form, hence L'Hospital rule can be applied to obtain:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{1}=f'(0)$.

Additionally, since $f(x)$ is smooth, $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ (Note that I have left out $0$). However, since from the L'Hospital rule $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(0)$, $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous on the complete interval $[0,1]$.

Finally, since $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous function on the bounded interval $[0,1]$, it follows that $\frac{f(x)}{x} \in L_2([0,1])$.

Thank you for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continuity on $(0,1]$ it is sufficient for $f$ to be continuous.  So the only question is what happens as $x\to 0$.  If you're using l'Hopital's rule then you're assuming that $f$ is right-differentiable as $x\to 0$ which is not necessary.  You just need to establish that $f \to 0$ faster than $x$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Hi Jpi, I have already stated that the continuity on $(0,1]$ comes from the continuity of $f(x)$. Also, $f(x)$ is smooth, thus it is right-differentiable.

Comment: Smoothness means different things to different people, but if you're assuming right-differentiability then sure.

Comment: And you don't need smoothness anywhere except in a small nbh around $x=0$.

Comment: Ah ok, I should have said that $f \in C^{\infty}([0,1])$. I will edit it. Thank you for your reply.